# Counting how often items appear in multiple lists, Python

Tags: python, json, list

So I have exported **210** WoT Replays into a .json file. Each battle is one object in there. And I want to count how many times [insert playername] appears in them. And I myself appear in all of them. But only **208** occurances are being counted 
The .json is strucured as follows:

```
[{...,...,"BothTeams":[{"Name":"player1",...}, {"Name":"player2",...},...],...}, {...,...,"BothTeams":[{"Name":"player1",...}, {"Name":"player2",...},...],...}]
```

And the code I use to iterate over it is the following:

```
for battle in skirmish_data:
    for index in range(14):
        name = battle["BothTeams"][index]["Name"]
        for player in Players:
            if name == player.name:
                player.battles += 1
```

Players is a list with Player objects and I use it to count. Each object has it's own amount of battles and it starts at 0, so logically it should give me the full amount but it doesn't. skirmish_data is the imported .json file.

I hope somebody knows what my problem is.

Edit: I tried it with a file containing only 172 entries and they got all counted.

Comment: what is the 14 in the range for?

Comment: So it only counts from 0 to 13, because in the list of "BothTeams" are only 14 entries